# Prove the following claim about skew symmetric matrix $\langle x,Ax\rangle =0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Vector_space_structure

> The real  $n\times n$ matrix ${\textstyle A}$ is skew-symmetric if and
>   only if
>
> ${\displaystyle \langle Ax,y\rangle =-\langle x,Ay\rangle \quad
>  \forall x,y\in \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$  This is also equivalent to
>    ${\textstyle \langle x,Ax\rangle =0}$ for all ${\displaystyle x\in
>  \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$

I am trying to show $\langle x,Ax\rangle =0$ but I don't really see it. If I had something like $$\langle x,Ax\rangle = -\langle x,A x\rangle$$ then I can claim $\langle x,Ax\rangle = 0$, but instead I have $$\langle x,Ax\rangle = -\langle x,A^\top x\rangle = -\langle Ax, x\rangle \neq 0 \quad (?)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\langle x,Ax\rangle\stackrel{\text{skew symmetry}}{=}-\langle Ax,x\rangle=
-\langle x,Ax\rangle\\
\implies 2\langle x,Ax\rangle=0\\
\implies \langle x,Ax\rangle=0
$$

Comment: Oh, essentially the symmetry of the inner product...I see thanks

Comment: Yes exactly. No problem